# jquery ui resizeable plugin using mobile gesture pinch

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery-UI resize plugin along with `jquery.ui.touch-punch` to allow resize to work on android and iOS devices, problem is that it still can't understand gestures like pinch to resize div.

```
$('.panel').resizable({
                containment: "parent",
                minHeight: 200,
                minWidth: 300,
                handles: 'sw,se',
                start:function(){panel.data('maximized',false);}
});
```

is it possible to hook pitch gesture to resizable? Or is there any other libraries like touch-punch that support gestures? At least pinching?

Comment: did you find something for that?